# Magento 2: How to remove decimal points from the price

Tags: magento2, price

I need to remove the two decimals from product prices on the frontend. For example, if the price is $49.00 it should be displayed as $49.

Since my products have no floating points it is ok to remove decimals in my case. On the product page, it seems like the price is loaded using JavaScript, so it is hard to do it by changing `price/amount/default.phtml`. Can someone suggest a proper method?

Comment: You can use extension for it. It is simple extension. https://github.com/lillik/magento2-price-decimal

Comment: Just a word of warning with using 'github.com/lillik/magento2-price-decimal' as it has issues where it strips the thousand operator making $1,299 equal $1. Had issues using this module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the module. You can review or [Download](https://github.com/lillik/magento2-price-decimal) from here.

Answer (score 4):

You need to override `vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/base/web/js/price-utils.js` and change the value of precision on line 38:

from

```
var precision = isNaN(format.requiredPrecision = Math.abs(format.requiredPrecision)) ? 2 : format.requiredPrecision,
```

to

```
var precision = 0,
```

Comment: how to override it?

Comment: Therefore you would have to add a requirejs-config.js file to some module (/app/code/VENDOR/MODULE/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js) with content var config = {

    map: {

        '*': {

            "Magento_Catalog/js/price-utils": "VENDOR_MODULE/js/price-utils"

        }

    }

}; Then create a file price-utils.js like /app/code/VENDOR/MODULE/view/frontend/web/js/price-utils.js. For German explanation please see [here](https://www.econcess.de/blog/onlineshop-erstellung-magento/247-onlineshop-magento-2-preise-ohne-nachkommastellen)

Answer (score 2):

You can do it using number_format funciton of php.

```
$price = 99.99;
number_format($price, 0, '.', '');
result : 99
```

Comment: what I need is , remove decimal points from magento using a module

Answer (score 0):

You can do using price helper class

```
$this->helper('Magento\Framework\Pricing\Helper\Data')->currency(number_format(50,2),true,false);
```

Comment: I may able to change using this approach in one place but what I need is to change it globally which mean it should appear anywhere we use price block

Comment: Using Plugin you need to customize public method currency in following class  Magento\Framework\Pricing\Helper\Data

Comment: I checked that file but it seems it is not using PRECISION in currency method

Comment: You need to customization using after plugin method. Also if you have knowledge regarding interface check PriceCurrencyInterface so you get some idea.

Comment: ok I will check

Comment: may i know for which function i need to write plugin so that i can change decimal symbol

Comment: public function format method in vendor\magento\framework\Pricing\PriceCurrencyInterface.php File.

Answer (score 0):

Just get the price as a normal attribute and then apply the currencyModel

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance(); // Instance of Object Manager
$currencyModel = $objectManager->create('Magento\Directory\Model\Currency'); // Instance of Currency Model
//get currency symbol by currency code
$currencyCode = 'GBP';
$currencySymbol = $currencyModel->load($currencyCode)->getCurrencySymbol();
$precision = 0;   // for displaying price decimals 2 point
```

...

```
$annualPrice = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('price')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product);

$annualPrice = $currencyModel->format($annualPrice, ['symbol' => $currencySymbol, 'precision'=> $precision], false, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

Follow the below blog post for changing the Price formatting. You will require to override the format class of Magento `Magento\Framework\Locale\Format` your custom module. And then override the function `getPriceFormat` in format class.

> https://webkul.com/blog/change-format-price-magento-2/

In the code, by changing `requiredPrecision => 0`, it will set values without decimals.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

We are using this free Open Source module: https://github.com/lillik/magento2-price-decimal.

Easy install and configuration. Manages front and backend.

Answer (score 0):

For frontend in Adobe Commerce 2.4.4

Create a before Plugin, with

```
$precision = 0
```

for
vendor/magento/module-directory/Model/Currency.php

formatPrecision(

```
public function formatPrecision(
    $price,
    $precision,
    $options = [],
    $includeContainer = true,
    $addBrackets = false
) {
```

Answer (score -2):

You can do using

```
app\code\core\Mage\Directory\Model\Currency.php
```

you find the following code :

```
public function formatTxt($price, $options = array()) {
        if (!is_numeric($price)) {
                $price = Mage::app()->getLocale()->getNumber($price);
        }
        /**
         * Fix problem with 12 000 000, 1 200 000
         *
         * %f - the argument is treated as a float, and presented as a floating-point number (locale aware).
         * %F - the argument is treated as a float, and presented as a floating-point number (non-locale aware).
         */
        $price = sprintf("%F", $price);
        if ($price == -0) {
                $price = 0;
        }

        return Mage::app()->getLocale()->currency($this->getCode())->toCurrency($price, $options);
    }
```

and change with the following code :

```
public function formatTxt($price, $options = array()) {
        if (!is_numeric($price)) {
                $price = Mage::app()->getLocale()->getNumber($price);
        }
        /**
         * Fix problem with 12 000 000, 1 200 000
         *
         * %f - the argument is treated as a float, and presented as a floating-point number (locale aware).
         * %F - the argument is treated as a float, and presented as a floating-point number (non-locale aware).
         */
        $price = sprintf("%F", $price);
        if ($price == -0) {
                $price = 0;
        }


        $options["precision"] = 0;
        if (isset($options["precision"])) {
                $price = round($price, $options["precision"]);
            }


        return Mage::app()->getLocale()->currency($this->getCode())->toCurrency($price, $options);
    }
```

Comment: the question was for Magento 2, not Magento 1

Comment: and to change the core is not the best option I think. Plugin suggested.