# Magento 2: How to remove price decimal

Tags: magento2, price

How to remove the price decimal from Front end price display only on the category and product pages ?

Comment: For the front end price display on the category and product pages? or are you asking about another part of the site?

Answer (score 9):

If you turn on the template hints for your site you will see the price is set in this template:

```
/vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/base/templates/product/price/amount/default.phtml
```

Copy this file into your theme

```
(app/design/frontend/{{namespace}}/{{theme_name}}/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/price/amount/default.phtml).
```

Take note of the class that this file is defined from

```
\Magento\Framework\Pricing\Render\Amount
```

The price itself is coming from this call:

```
<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->formatCurrency($block->getDisplayValue(), (bool)$block->getIncludeContainer()) ?>
```

If we take a look at the file that this method is created based on the class it's inheriting (`/vendor/magento/framework/Pricing/Render/Amount.php`) you will see this method:

```
/**
 * Format price value
 *
 * @param float $amount
 * @param bool $includeContainer
 * @param int $precision
 * @return float
 */
public function formatCurrency(
    $amount,
    $includeContainer = true,
    $precision = PriceCurrencyInterface::DEFAULT_PRECISION
) {
    return $this->priceCurrency->format($amount, $includeContainer, $precision);
}
```

Taking note of the perams in the method, we can see from the template that is displaying the price that we have the definition for the `$amount` and the `$includeContainer` but not for the last one `$precision` which defaults to the constant `PriceCurrencyInterface::DEFAULT_PRECISION`. This constant is defined in the file `/vendor/magento/framework/Pricing/PriceCurrencyInterface.php`. Looking in this file we see at the top of the file just after the interface is defined `const DEFAULT_PRECISION = 2;`. So in the templale we just have to redefine this constant and it will change the default precision based on this value. Setting the value to `0` will do the trick for the category page and for the product page.

Change:

```
<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->formatCurrency($block->getDisplayValue(), (bool)$block->getIncludeContainer()) ?>
```

to:

```
<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->formatCurrency($block->getDisplayValue(), (bool)$block->getIncludeContainer(), 0) ?>
```

## Note

This works on the site that I tested on, using USDs. Because Magento supports international currencies and different translations, this method might not work exactly as it does for me. But I don't have any international site set up right now, so I'm not able to test.

Comment: That is perfect working fine wherever there is a price except in product page

Comment: Yeah, i just saw that. The price get reloaded and changed with some JS in this file `/vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/base/web/js/price-box.js`. I just need to look into how to override this behavior.

Comment: I found this while looking around, it's not an answer to the question, but might get you down the right path. http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/112102/magento2-how-can-i-override-core-js-module-price-box-js

Comment: I think this in combination with the JS solution is the right answer to the question. PHP handles rendering the prices from the server, whereas JS handles rendering the dynamically written prices (like in the minicart or when switching between options for configurable products).

Comment: this is awesome answer.. can you tell me how to remove decimal from product details page

Answer (score 7):

To correct the product page you also should modify next javascript:

```
/vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/base/web/js/price-utils.js
```

on line 38 change

```
var precision = isNaN(format.requiredPrecision = Math.abs(format.requiredPrecision)) ? 2 : format.requiredPrecision,
```

for

```
var precision = 0,
```

Hope this help.

I found this in: [Magento 2 : How to remove decimal points from the price](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/96534/magento-2-how-to-remove-decimal-points-from-the-price)

Comment: Don't modify core files, since they will be overwritten when you upgrade or re-install your installation. Rather use an override in your own design like where the article links to suggests.

Comment: Therefore you would have to add a requirejs-config.js file to some module (/app/code/VENDOR/MODULE/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js) with content var config = {

    map: {

        '*': {

            "Magento_Catalog/js/price-utils": "VENDOR_MODULE/js/price-utils"

        }

    }

}; Then create a file price-utils.js like /app/code/VENDOR/MODULE/view/frontend/web/js/price-utils.js. For German explanation please see [here](https://www.econcess.de/blog/onlineshop-erstellung-magento/247-onlineshop-magento-2-preise-ohne-nachkommastellen)

Answer (score 7):

The price-utils.js solution did not work for me.

But this worked in Magento 2.1: Look in
`/vendor/magento/framework/Pricing/PriceCurrencyInterface.php`

Change 
`const DEFAULT_PRECISION = 2;`

To
`const DEFAULT_PRECISION = 0;`

Then flush cache.

Comment: Hi, I tried this answer and changed price in frontend only. how to change in backend also ?

Comment: its work for me but edit vendor file not good practices

Comment: you can find proper override of PriceCurrencyInterface using custom module in that answer https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/211894/23264

Answer (score 1):

You can use this module

> https://github.com/lillik/magento2-price-decimal

if you are using composer, just run

```
composer require lillik/magento2-price-decimal
```

Comment: This module caused several issues for us, product prices was corrupted

Comment: While you create new product it mess up all product prices,  if a product price is 2,500 it will become 2 as it will remove all digits which come after comma (,) in price.

Comment: Its not working , product price getting corrupted totally..........

Answer (score 0):

Change this in the file price-utils.js

from

```
            (precision ? decimalSymbol + am.toFixed(2).replace(/-/, 0).slice(2) : '');
```

to

```
            (precision ? decimalSymbol + am.toFixed(format.requiredPrecision).replace(/-/, 0).slice(2) : '');
```

It will dynamically load price precision and you don't have to do anything in js file.Just change in php file and will reflect here :)

Answer (score 0):

I fixed method *formatPrecision* in *vendor/magento/module-directory/Model/Currency.php* on line ~301
there was code:

```
if (!isset($options['precision'])) {
    $options['precision'] = $precision;
}
```

I fixed so

```
if (!isset($options['precision'])) {
    $options['precision'] = ( (floatval($price) - intval($price)) != 0 ? $precision : 0);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

To get desired result you have to edit this file

```
/pub/static/frontend/Theme-Package/Theme-Name/en_US/Magento_Catalog/js/price-utils.js
```

at line 38

```
var precision = isNaN(format.requiredPrecision = Math.abs(format.requiredPrecision)) ? 2 : format.requiredPrecision,
```

replace this with

```
var precision = 0,
```

This is for magento2.1.3
this will remove decimals from price digits. This solution helped me

Comment: Realize that static generated files (the files in `pub/static`) are overwritten every time you run `setup:static-content:deploy`. So I wouldn't make this modification here, but rather override `/vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/base/web/js/price-utils.js`, like Diego suggested.

Comment: don't modify pub/static as mentioned by Giel already.