# Remove .00 decimal from price

Tags: magento-2.1, price

how to remove only ".00" decimal from price in magento2?

For Example,

$500.00 => $500

$19.99  => $19.99

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Take a look here, it might help answer or at least clarify what you are looking to do: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/122808/magento-2-how-to-remove-price-decimal/122845#122845

Comment: I have created a simple extension for this, give it a try: https://github.com/adarshkhatri/price-decimal-magento2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find from below github link for price decimal setting in magento 2,

[Price Decimal Setting for Magento 2](https://github.com/lillik/magento2-price-decimal)

After installing extension in your site you need to just set configuration from **Stores -> Configuration.**

Comment: I posted this question 1 year ago tho. But still it will help for other developers who are looking for this kind functionality. I am accepting your answer and upvote. Thanks for sharing.

Comment: but this answer doesn't meets the qst. This extension hides all decimal. Not only `.00`.

Comment: for anyone who is going to use this module , this module has issues !! If you are facing issue with product price update from the backend , this could very well be because of this module . The issue that you will face is price 10,000 usd will be changed to 10 usd after saving the product from the backend . you can refer this open issue at https://github.com/lillik/magento2-price-decimal/issues/41

Answer (score 0):

You need overwrite the method  getPriceFormat of the class Format.

```
<preference for="Magento\Framework\Locale\Format" type="My\MODULE\Model\Format" />
```

In your class format

```
 public function getPriceFormat($localeCode = null, $currencyCode = null)
   {
    .
    .
    $result = [
        //TODO: change interface
        'pattern' => $currency->getOutputFormat(),
        'precision' => 0,
        'requiredPrecision' => 0,
        'decimalSymbol' => $decimalSymbol,
        'groupSymbol' => $groupSymbol,
        'groupLength' => $group,
        'integerRequired' => $integerRequired,
    ];
   }
```

result 3,858 before 3,858.00

Comment: Hey, I tried your solution but it'll do rounding of the price. for example, $4.50 => $5...

Comment: This solution works for me.

Comment: I TRIED  but it is not working for me. We can make product grid price and cost price with 2 precision point