# Need to remove decimal from Discount Price Magento 2

Tags: magento2

I want to remove decimal digits from discount price on product details page in magento 2.Any solution.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you can use `floor()` function for remove decimal digits from discount price
[Reference](http://php.net/manual/en/function.floor.php)

Answer (score 0):

To correct the product page you also should modify next javascript:

```
/vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/base/web/js/price-utils.js
```

on line 38 change

```
var precision = isNaN(format.requiredPrecision = Math.abs(format.requiredPrecision)) ? 2 : format.requiredPrecision,
```

for

```
var precision = 0,
```

Hope this help.

I found this in: [Magento 2 : How to remove decimal points from the price](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/96534/magento-2-how-to-remove-decimal-points-from-the-price)