# Magento2: How to remove decimal points from price in product admin grid

Tags: magento2, price, admin-panel, product-grid

I want to remove decimal points for price in product admin grid.

[image]

I have follow [this](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/96534/magento-2-how-to-remove-decimal-points-from-the-price) but it only remove the decimal from frontend.

Answer (score 1):

in file vendor/magento/module-catalog/Ui/Component/Listing/Columns/Price.php

change line number 65

```
$item[$fieldName] = $currency->toCurrency(sprintf("%f", $item[$fieldName]));
```

with

```
$item[$fieldName] = round($item[$fieldName]);
```

https://drops.meetanshi.com/oUmpWy

Comment: Thanks @Jigs it working for me

Comment: @PurushotamSharma it will create issue when are going to upgrade magento 2 version. give specific solution to override this in your local module

Comment: @Jigs: it also removed Currency symbol from price

Comment: yes it remove the currency symbol, if you dont want to remove it, than you need to just change in the same line

Answer (score 0):

I have override this using custom module:-

app/code/Vendor/Module/registration.php

```
<?php

\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Vendor_Module',
    __DIR__
);
```

app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Vendor_Module" setup_version="1.0.0">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Catalog"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

app/code/Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/ui_component/product_listing.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <columns name="product_columns" class="Magento\Catalog\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns">
        <column name="price" class="Vendor\Module\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Price">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">textRange</item>
                    <item name="add_field" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Price</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">74</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
    </columns>
</listing>
```

app/code/Vendor/Module/Ui/Component/Listing/Columns/Price.php

```
<?php 

namespace Vendor\Module\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns;

use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponentFactory;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\ContextInterface;

class Price extends \Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Column
{
    /**
     * Column name
     */
    const NAME = 'column.price';

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Locale\CurrencyInterface
     */
    protected $localeCurrency;

    /**
     * @param ContextInterface $context
     * @param UiComponentFactory $uiComponentFactory
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Locale\CurrencyInterface $localeCurrency
     * @param \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
     * @param array $components
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        ContextInterface $context,
        UiComponentFactory $uiComponentFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\Locale\CurrencyInterface $localeCurrency,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        array $components = [],
        array $data = []
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context, $uiComponentFactory, $components, $data);
        $this->localeCurrency = $localeCurrency;
        $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
    }

    /**
     * Prepare Data Source
     *
     * @param array $dataSource
     * @return array
     */
    public function prepareDataSource(array $dataSource)
    {
        if (isset($dataSource['data']['items'])) {
            $store = $this->storeManager->getStore(
                $this->context->getFilterParam('store_id', \Magento\Store\Model\Store::DEFAULT_STORE_ID)
            );
            $currency = $this->localeCurrency->getCurrency($store->getBaseCurrencyCode());

            $fieldName = $this->getData('name');
            foreach ($dataSource['data']['items'] as & $item) {
                if (isset($item[$fieldName])) {
                    //$item[$fieldName] = $currency->toCurrency(sprintf("%f", $item[$fieldName]));
                    $item[$fieldName] = round($item[$fieldName]);
                }
            }
        }

        return $dataSource;
    }
}
```

Hope this will help.